# Load/split a .txt into multiple listboxes.?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, listbox, openfiledialog, file.readalllines

I am trying to figure out a way to load a  very large .txt file and thought if I break it into sections (Listboxes) it would load faster and be easier to manipulate with less lag. Or is there a way to OFD with a background worker?
Here is how I am loading the .txt

```
      TextBox1.Text = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Load File"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:temp"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    TextBox1.Text = path
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextBox1.Text)
```

I can go in and mark every 1/4 of the .txt with a delimiter if that would help?
I was thinking if I iterate through XX amount of lines then Next listbox etc. Maybe some form of items.count in a if not statement? My mind is going in circles please aim me in the best direction. My file is 25.MB and growing slowly. Notepad++ is the only thing handling it well ATM.

```
     ListBox1.Items.Add(lines(1 - 10000))
```

throws an error ("Outside array index or similar")

```
       ListBox1.Items.Add(lines(10000))
```

Loads the single line

Comment: You're loading it on the UI thread. So the more data to load the longer it is going to take. You should load the file into a DataTable and then bind the datatable to the listbox once you are finished loading the file into the datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something along the lines of this. This is not 100% accurate code. But to give you an idea.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
Dim lines As New List(Of [String])()
lines = New List(Of [String])(File.ReadLines(ofDialog.FileName))
Task.Run(Function() 
Dim options As New ParallelOptions()
options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = CInt(1)//Number of threads to spawn

Parallel.ForEach(lines, options, Function(line) 
    dt.Rows.Add()
End Function)
Me.Invoke(DirectCast(Sub() listview.DataSource = dt, MethodInvoker))

End Function)
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, I will give this a go right now.

Comment: May have another way, but still could use your expertise.

Comment: I chose this as the correct answer seeing how this is the proper way of doing it

Comment: If you need more help. Please let me know